# How can I accumulate data of multiple hosts and process it at once in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to collect data from multiple hosts and process it at once afterwards, e. g. comparing data of one host with the data of the other hosts. This is what I tried:

```yaml
- name: Play 1
  hosts: multiplehosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Accumulate data
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        data: '{{ data | default([]) + [''foobar''] }}'
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

- name: Play 2
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Process data
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: data
```

Unfortunately, the accumulation does not work. The fact `data` will contain `foobar` only once, even for multiple hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a in-a-nutshell start point:

```yaml
- hosts: multiplehosts
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        some_var: "a host specific value"

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'some_var') }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Why `ansible_play_hosts` instead of `group['multiplehost']`? => because the first does not contain hosts which failed and might not contain the data you are looking for (hence causing an error). See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

Answer (score 1):

In the expression below, if there are unreachable hosts you'll get a shorter list. But, you don't know which hosts are missing

```yaml
  some_var_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                     map('extract', hostvars, 'some_var') }}"
```

If this is a problem you can create a dictionary

```yaml
  some_var_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                          zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                              map('extract', hostvars, 'some_var'))) }}"
```

Then you can get the list too

```yaml
  some_var_list: "{{ some_var_dict.values()|list }}"
```